# Подскажите библиотеку для фоторедактора

Tags: vue.js, поиск-библиотек, редактор

Стоит задача сделать простой фоторедактор. В разработке использую vue.js, по требованиям надо иметь возможность пользоваться карандашом, отметить на фото что то кругом, квадратом или стрелкой, и иметь возможность изменить цвет выделителя. Конечно в перспективе хотим иметь больше возможностей.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, у кого был подобный опыт, может какие то библиотеки которыми удобно пользоваться для такого фоторедактора?